# Получение динамических $_GET и вывод Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется массив следующего вида:

```
array(2) {
  ["brand"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["size"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
}
```

Как в цикле вывести отношение название/содержание?
Что бы на выходе получить следующий вид:

```
Brand (1)
Size (8)
```

Пытался делать вот так:

```
foreach($request->input() as $row) {
   echo $row[0];
   foreach($row as $item) {
      echo $item;
   }
}
```

Судя по всему то что я делаю нелогично. Как решить вопрос?

Comment: Так в чем вопрос то? Что именно вам не нравится в вашей реализации? На каком "выходе" должны появиться эти строки?

Comment: Ошибка выводится, надпись Array

Answer (score 0):

*телепат моде он*

```
foreach($request->input() as $key => $value) {
   echo $key."(".$value[0].")";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если все правильно понял, то так:

```
$data = request()->data;

foreach($data['brand'] as $key => $value) {
    return $value . ' - ' . $data['size'][$key];
}
```